# php regex to check if a string starts with a specific string including the lang code

Tags: php, regex

I have two strings like

`/en/user/abc` and
`/user/abc`

I want to check if the above strings starts with `/user/`. The condition should return true in the above both cases. So the regex should consider a possible langcode also.

I used this regex.

```
if (preg_match('#^/user/#i', $url) === 1) {
 echo 'yes';   
}
```

it works fine but I don't know how to handle the possible lang code in the string.

OR If I can get `/user/abc` from the above two strings? Then I can use the above regex.

Comment: Use `^(?:/en)?/user/`

Comment: but there should be another lang code also like i-e `nl`, `de` etc

Comment: Then use `~^(?:/[a-z]{2})?/user/~`

Answer (score 1):

You can either add all the language codes to your regex: `^(?:\/(?:en|de|nl))\/user`

See: https://regex101.com/r/T7HxoD/4

Or allow any two characters: `^(?:\/[a-z]{2})?\/user`

See: https://regex101.com/r/T7HxoD/3

Comment: You don't have to escape the `\/` as the delimiter that the OP uses is `#`